# How to update Flask apps to production server

Tags: python, git, deployment, flask

This is my first question in stack overflow, i always found my answers here and now is time to ask on something that i can't resolve.

I been searching on google about this but i couldnt resolve my problems.

I want to create a project in python using Flask. I know how to setup the server to run the app, i'm using

1. Ubuntu Server 12.04
2. Apache
3. Flask Python
4. Digital Ocean Production Server
5. Elementary OS for Development Computer

I know how to configure the app following this tutorial on [digital ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-deploy-a-flask-application-on-an-ubuntu-vps)

I want to be "profesional" i came from PHP and normaly i used FTP to uploading my changes from my computer to the production server. Someone in my last job configured SVN as control version to update the production server.

I need something similar for my project but i dont know how to do it. If i edited a .py file in my computer and upload the file via FTP the changes doesnt reflect in my browser. I have to restart apache o the entire server to see that changes, and of course thats not a clever way to work.

I really need help to setup a workflow using git, the idea is simple. I'll install git in my computer to work and git in my production server and i want to deploy and update the app using git and see the changes on the app (watching my browser) but my 
questions are

how i can do this setup? and do i have to execute any command on my production server any time that i commit an update from my computer? or everything will be automaticaly with git.

I'll apreciate the answers and the help casue i'm discouraged and i dont want to back to PHP

Comment: What are you using to run your application inside Apache? mod_wsgi?

Comment: yes i use mod_wsgi i installed libapache2-mod-wsgi

Comment: With mod_wsgi you shouldn't have to restart Apache. You should be able to just touch the script being loaded by mod_wsgi. For example `touch /path/to/wsgi.py`.

Comment: If you're really set on using Git, you may want to take a look at [Dokku](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-use-the-digitalocean-dokku-application).

Answer (score 1):

I am using the same configuration as you are (except I use Ubuntu 14.04) and found the following two tutorials extremely helpful. If I understand what you are asking, this should push you on your way:

1. [How to Set Up Automatic Deployment with Git on a VPS](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-set-up-automatic-deployment-with-git-with-a-vps)
2. [How to Deploy a Flask Application on an Ubuntu VPS](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-deploy-a-flask-application-on-an-ubuntu-vps)

You listed the second tutorial already, so the first one should show you how to set up git to push-deploy to your server. It also shows you how to set up a beta branch in case you don't want to push to prod right away!

Answer (score 0):

The short, general answer is that in Python you'd use a deployment tool, with a set of deployment scripts.

Popular deployment tool choices for Python include [Fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/) and [Paver](http://paver.github.io/paver/). These tools essentially facilitate the creation of "task" scripts, which you can then run. They are geared towards deployment, so they provide library functions that execute actions on remote servers.

Per your example, you can write a script for Fabric that would connect to the remote server, upload the code by SFTP, and restart your server gracefully.

I strongly suggest investing the time to learn and use one of these tools. Beyond the obvious advantages, they have many non-obvious benefits for long term usage, for example: much easier to scale across multiple deployment target boxes.

Comment: thanks for the answer but seems to be quit complicated to create a script to do automatically all my manual stuff on my production server. And i dont think that is the right way, im still loking for the set up with git

Comment: Your Fabric task could use Git.

Comment: @CharlieEspinoza: Learning to use a proper deployment tool may seem like a big investment, but you did want to do this professionally, and that's how it's done in the professional development world. Like dirn said, you can make Fabric use Git if you insist. That said, Git is not a deployment tool. It doesn't track empty directories, nor file permissions. Once you use Fabric, your perceived need to use Git will greatly diminish. You will also gain many additional capabilities, such as deploying to multiple boxes - not that many professional projects use a single box anymore.

Comment: hi thanks all for your comments. Finally i implemented Fabric for deployment.

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete solution, but take a look at [gitreceive](https://github.com/progrium/gitreceive). This is a small bash script that you run on your production server to configure it to receive code via `git push`.

I say it is not a complete solution because all gitreceive does is call a script that you have to write with the files that were pushed. Your script has to install the files, run any setup tasks, restart the server, etc.